# To get a token with the OpenID Connect flow I always need a manual REST call

Tags: spring-boot, authentication, spring-security, oauth-2.0, openid-connect

While implementing a simple Authorization client with spring security and spring OAuth2 my goal is to obtain an access token.

According to the OpenID Connect flow (https://oauth.com/playground/oidc.html) there is a first step where a redirect from the OAuth Server occurs and an authorization code and state are given, which in my case it successfully happens.

On a second step a POST request needs to be made to a tokenUrl with contentType "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" and a body with clientId, clientSecret, grant_type and the (authorization) code.

This second request though needs to be made manually from me in order to get the token, because otherwise the flow stops in the first step as it can be seen in my screenshot.

Can someone tell me how to configure the spring application so that the two steps are made automatically?

The properties I´ve set are:

```
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.my-idp.client-id=TestControlSuiteDev
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.my-idp.client-secret=<secret-here>
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.my-idp.authorization-grant-type=authorization_code
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.my-idp.scope=openid,email,profile
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.my-idp.redirect-uri=http://localhost:8900/v4/loginWithOpenId 

spring.security.oauth2.client.provider.my-idp.issuer-uri=<oauth-url>
spring.security.oauth2.client.provider.my-idp.authorization-uri=<oauth-authorize-url>
spring.security.oauth2.client.provider.my-idp.token-uri=<oauth-token-url>
```

and my configuration bean looks like this:

```
@Configuration
    public class SecurityConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain defaultSecurityFilterChain(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
        return httpSecurity.authorizeHttpRequests(authorizeConfig -> {
            authorizeConfig.antMatchers("/v4/register").authenticated();
            authorizeConfig.anyRequest().permitAll();
        }).oauth2Login(Customizer.withDefaults()).build();
        
    }

}
```

As a quick fix I changed the redirect endpoint to do the POST request as follows:

```
@GetMapping(path = "/loginWithOpenId")
    public String oauthLogin(HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest) throws JsonProcessingException {
    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();

    HttpHeaders httpHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
    httpHeaders.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED);

    String code = httpServletRequest.getParameter("code");

    String requestBody = "grant_type=authorization_code&code="+code+"&client_id="+clientId+"&client_secret="+clientSecret;

    HttpEntity<String> entity = new HttpEntity<>(requestBody, httpHeaders);

    ResponseEntity<String> response = restTemplate.postForEntity(tokenUri, entity, String.class);

    Map<String, String> map = new ObjectMapper().readValue(response.getBody(), Map.class);
    return map.get("access_token");
}
```

But my expectation is that this manual step shouldn´t be necessary

Comment: You should not have to write any of the authorization code flow requests yourself. See the "client" tutorials I wrote there: https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons/tree/master/samples/tutorials

Comment: @ch4mp May i know which tutorial should i look at, as i also encounter the same issue.

Comment: If you follow the link, you'll find a README. If you read it, you should find the answer to this question.

Comment: @NickWills I have the same problem, did you manage to find a solution?